# I have a particular error when I truncate a double in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Everything works perfectly except when you try to truncate the number "9741.8". In my unitest it works fine, the correct result should be "9741.80" but at the moment the application executes it the result is "9741.79". Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

This is my function:

```
fun Double.formatTwoDecimals(): String{
    val format = DecimalFormat("0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ROOT))
    format.roundingMode = RoundingMode.DOWN
    format.format(this)
}
```

error:

[image]

expected result:

[image]

Comment: In your extension function add a `println(this)` statement and see what the application is inputting as its value. Maybe it is not passing in what you expect

Comment: Your test doesn’t assert anything so it will always pass.

Comment: You should work with Big Number if you need a perfect decimal.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. Teddy Smith's comment helped me find this link https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio. Fix problem using Bigdecimal